# Create DLL from unmanaged C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, cmake, unmanaged

I currently have a console application written in unmanaged C++, the source code consists of an entry-point `main` and some other functions.  I need to create a DLL from this code so that I can use it from other projects, specifically from managed C++.  (Another question: would I have to write a wrapper class for this purpose?)

As I know next to nothing of managed/unmanaged C++ and creating DLLs, I followed [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.80).aspx) and managed to get a simple Hello World DLL up and running by using only VS2010 (no CMake).

However, this project of mine has a lot of dependencies (e.g. [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/)), and so I normally use CMake to generate the Visual Studio 2010 solution that then builds into an executable, as described in the [PCL Tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl_pcl_config.php#using-pcl-pcl-config).  How can I use CMake to build a VS2010 project that will build into a DLL?

To summarise my problem:

1. I have a project of unmanaged C++ code that needs a lot of dependencies.
2. I want to create a DLL from this code that can be called from managed C++.

Extra information:
Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, CMake 2.8.10.2

**EDIT:**
I used CMake with your line changed, and it worked as expected.  This is what I have since added to my header file, am I on the right track?

MyCode.h

```
#ifdef MyLib_EXPORTS
#define API_DECL __declspec( dllexport )
#else 
#define API_DECL __declspec( dllimport )

#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/...>
etc...

API_DECL void myFirstFunction();
API_DECL void mySecondFunction();
#endif
```

MyCode.cpp: I have not made any changes to the source file, should I make any?

Comment: Your `#endif` should close before including `iostream`.

Comment: I think I've got my DLL working.  Now to to deal with the unmanaged/managed situation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I cannot help you with the managed code part, but this is how you create a DLL in CMake:

First of all, instead of using

```
`ADD_EXECUTABLE( YourLib SHARED yourclass.cpp yourclass.h )`
```

in your `CMakeLists.txt`, use

```
`ADD_LIBRARY( YourLib SHARED yourclass.cpp yourclass.h )`
```

This will configure the solution to create a DLL rather than an executable.

However, to be able to use this DLL with your projects, you need to export the symbols you want to use. To do this, you need to add `__declspec( dllexport )` to your class and/or function declarations. Building the library will then yield two files, a .`dll` and a `.lib`. The latter one is the so-called import library that you need when you want to use this library in your other projects. The `.dll` will be required at runtime.

**However**: When you want to use your library, you need to use `__declspec( dllimport)` (rather than `dllexport`). To avoid using two header files, the usual way to do this is to use the preprocessor. CMake actually helps you by providing a `YourLibrary_EXPORTS` `define` in your library project.

To summarize:

```
#ifndef YOUR_CLASS_H
#define YOUR_CLASS_H

#ifdef YourLib_EXPORTS
#define API_DECL __declspec( dllexport )
#else 
#define API_DECL __declspec( dllimport )
#endif

class APIDECL YourClass  {
   void foo();
   void bar();
};

#endif // YOUR_CLASS_H
```

EDIT: 
If you want to be able to use those functions from C (and languages that are able to use C functions) you should wrap your declarations with `extern "C" {`

```
extern "C" {
    API_DECL void myFirstFunction();
    API_DECL void mySecondFunction();
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I just want to check some things.  Does this mean that my function declarations, e.g. `mainFunc(int a)` should change to `__declspec( dllexport ) mainFunc(int a)`?

Comment: No, you wouldn't export your `main` function (at least not `main` or `WinMain`). That would collide with the main function in the executable that will link to this library. However, if you need to call specific code when the dll is loaded, have a look at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx](DllMain).

Comment: Sorry for messing up the link in the previous comment: This is the correct one [`DllMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Okay, I think I understand.  So this means that I will only need to re-declare those functions that I want to be accessible from outside?  In my case, it will be good enough to only have the `main` function be accessible, so should I rather opt to just use `DllMain`?

Comment: If it's a function that you want to use outside (it's a library), I would clearly suggest to call your function differently. And then just call it by that name.

Comment: Yes, after thinking about it I realised that this would make more sense.  I have made an edit to my question to provide some additional clarity, could you please check if I am still doing it correctly?  Thanks for your help so far!