# How to create a DLL from a VS solution build by CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm trying to use a time-of-flight camera, the flexx2 by PMD in a unity application. The API for the camera is written in C++, so I need to create a DLL to use it in unity.

I use CMake to build the binaries in C++, this takes my .cpp file and creates a visual studio project. The project builds into debug folder with an exe, and I need to add two dlls to the debug folder to get the exe to run properly.

How can I make it so that everything builds into a DLL that I can use from unity? Or is there an easier way to expose the API to unity?

I tried to figure out how to change the build target, but right click project -> properties doesn't show me the "application" tab with the "output type" option.

Comment: [Create DLL from unmanaged C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462049/create-dll-from-unmanaged-c) has some information on how to create a DLL with cmake, but if the original source code was not created with that in mind you may have issues and need to export symbols and such.